# "A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected" error message

Tags: sklearn-pandas

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis

clf = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
clf.fit(np.matrix(X_train), np.matrix(y_train))
```

but I get the error message. Specified above.

I checked the shape of y_train but it's (294,1).
tried the ravel() thing but it then it's (1,294) and if I transpose it then it looks back how it did before the ravel().

X_train.shape is (294,8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, don't use `np.matrix`, use `np.array` instead, its no longer recommended to use this class.

Try this:

```py
clf.fit(X_train, np.ravel(y_train))
```

Comment: Glad is was able to help!

Comment: One more follow up question. Should also be casting my X_train data to np.array? or is a matrix okay for that one?

Comment: If your data was not already of type array, you have to convert it to np.array before feeding it to the classifier. np.matrix returns an array-like object, thats why its not recommended to use np.matrix in this context.